# What is the difference between SUR and OLS?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

How is the output different in the [SUR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seemingly_unrelated_regressions) (Seemingly Unrelated Regressions) equation from the OLS? Is it still the same as Bo + B1x = y?